# Remove image by src

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I need to remove certain images with a specific `src`:

http://ukn.cs-mtc.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/page-addon/thumbnail.gif

Is there a way to remove the whole `<img>` tag with JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had some free time (and a strange urge to write some JavaScript...), so I thought I'd offer this functional approach:

```
function removeNeighbour(el, elType) {
    if (!el) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (el.nextElementSibling) {
        var nxt = el.nextElementSibling;
    }
    else {
        var nxt = el.nextSibling;
        while (nxt.nodeType !== 1 && nxt.nextSibling) {
            nxt = nxt.nextSibling;
        }

    }
    if (elType && nxt.tagName.toLowerCase() == elType.toLowerCase()) {
        nxt.parentNode.removeChild(nxt);
    }
    else if (!elType) {
        nxt.parentNode.removeChild(nxt);
    }
}

function clearElsWithAttrEquals(el, attr, val, andNeighbour, neighbourType) {
    if (!el || !attr || !val) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (document.querySelectorAll) {
        var matchingElems = document.querySelectorAll(el + '[' + attr + '="' + val + '"]'),
            neighbourType = neighbourType || '';
        for (var i = matchingElems.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (andNeighbour === true) {
                removeNeighbour(matchingElems[i], neighbourType);
            }
            matchingElems[i].parentNode.removeChild(matchingElems[i]);
        }
    }
    else {
        var matchingElems = document.getElementsByTagName(el),
            len = (matchingElems.length - 1);
        for (var i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (matchingElems[i][attr] == val) {
                matchingElems[i].parentNode.removeChild(matchingElems[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}

clearElsWithAttrEquals('img', 'src', 'http://ukn.cs-mtc.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/page-addon/thumbnail.gif', true, 'p');​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qpmVW/2/).

Quick guide to (and the only documentation I'm ever likely to write *for*) `clearElsWithAttrEquals()` function:

`clearElsWithAttrEquals(el, attr, val[, andNeighbour[, neighbourType]])`;

1. `el` : (**string**) identifies the element type ('img','p','span'...).
2. `attr` : (**string**) identifies which attribute you want to search by ('id', 'src', etc...)
3. `val` : (**string**) this will only match if the value is *exactly* equal to the string
4. `andNeighbour` : (**Boolean**, *optional*) do you want to remove the neighbouring element too? Pass `true` (if yes) or `false` (if not).
5. `neighbourType` : (**string**, *optional*) remove the neighbour only if it's of this element-type ('div','hr','span', etc) ; if omitted then the next sibling element will be removed *regardless* of its type.

References:

- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) ([Compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13)).
- [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling) ([Compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t83)).
- [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nextSibling) ([Compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t74)).
- [`node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType) ([Compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t21)).
- [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.parentNode) ([Compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t75)).
- [`removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild) ([Compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t93)).
- [`String.toLowerCase()`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase.html).
- [`while (condition) {/*...*/}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

Comment: I'm glad you like it! I'm not convinced it's necessarily better than jQuery (unless you just really want to avoid libraries). But it was fun to write and work through! Hope it's of use to you. =)

Answer (score 4):

Do you use jQuery? If so,

`$('img[src="http://ukn.cs-mtc.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/page-addon/thumbnail.gif"]').remove();` should work.

Otherwise...

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i=0,i<img.length;i++) {
if(img[i].src == 'http://ukn.cs-mtc.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/page-addon/thumbnail.gif') {
img[i].parentNode.removeChild(img[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: awesomem man, that worked :) but theres a <br> right after the image, is there a way to remove it as well?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$('img[src="<path>"]').remove();
```